# Default location for WCF svc logs

Tags: wcf, service, path

I have a WCF service which has logging enabled. But when i do not mention the path for the logs, the svc logs are getting created in "C:\" in this location. Is this the default location for the logs if we are not implicitly mentioned?

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose,ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source propagateActivity="true" name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Error">
    <listeners>
      <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add initializeData="\Logfilename.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
    <filter type="" />
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
 </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 3):

You're starting your path (`\Logfilename.svclog`) with a backslash (`\`), meaning "root of the current drive".

If you want the current (bin) directory, remove the backslash.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I want to know why these logs getting created in "C:\" if the config as in the question. I have deployed the service in G: drive.

Comment: @RinshadHameed read the answer again, the first sentence says why they end up in your root.

Comment: @nvoigt But my service bin is in G: drive

Comment: The service probably runs in IIS, having its current directory set to `C:\Windows\...`.